# Existence and regularity of solutions of elliptic PDE in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I try to find some references about the theory of elliptic PDE in an infinite domain. The references I am aware of (Brezis, Evans) present only the case where the equation is posed in bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Specifically I consider the following PDE in $\mathbb{R}^n$:

$$
A(x,y)^2u_{xx}+B(x,y)^2u_{yy}+C(x,y)u_x+D(x,y)u_y=0
$$

where $A,B,C$ and $D$ are $C^{\infty}$ smooth.

**Question**: When does a solution exists (I don't care of uniqueness) ? When is this solution $C^{\infty}$ smooth ?

Comment: You probably want to have a non homogeneous part as well. Otherwise $u=0$ is always a smooth solution.

Comment: Smoothness is a pointwise property and usual regularity theorems (in Evans or Gilbarg-Trudinger) can be used.

Comment: I effectively want a non constant solution .